# Fuzzy logic application in recommender system

Tags: artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I was wondering how can I get some kind of advantage with using fuzzy logic in my recommender system?

My system basically calculates similarity between users by:

- tanimoto coefficient
- cosinus distance
- discrete distance

Then all the similarities are combined into one that measures from 0 to 1.
So we can get similar users for user 1 and then recommend him goods that were bought by users who are similar to him.

I understand the basics of fuzzy theory, just can't think of any usage in here, but want to try 
Would like to hear any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen so many successful applications of fuzzy logic in real life, so I would not expect too much from it.

Why do you want to try it if you cannot think of any usage?

Comment: To get working experience with this theory, and to get better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

If your similarity value measures from 0 to 1, you can use fuzzy logic to formalize your system. Is like having a system that returns true/false and try to formalize it with bi-valued logic. You just get the formalization.

The only advantage can be defuzzifying the number (using fuzzy words like very similar, not very similar, ...), but you can do that without fuzzy logic too ...